# trying to save image in amazon s3 but image not getting saved

Tags: php, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to save images from image url to the amazon s3, but image is created there in bucket, but image is not shown in browser, displays message "image cannot be displayed because it contains error.

This is my code: 
    require_once("aws/aws-autoloader.php");

```
        // Amazon S3

        use Aws\S3\S3Client;

        // Create an Amazon S3 client object
        $s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX'
        ));

        // Register the stream wrapper from a client object
        $s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();

        // Save Thumbnail
        $s3Path = "s3://smmrescueimages/";
        $s3Stream = fopen($s3Path . 'gt.jpg', 'w');
        fwrite($s3Stream, 'http://sippy.in/gt.jpg');
        @fclose($s3Stream);
        echo "done";
```

This is the image path generated https://s3.amazonaws.com/smmrescueimages/gt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
fwrite($s3Stream, 'http://sippy.in/gt.jpg');
```

to

```
fwrite($s3Stream, file_get_contents('http://sippy.in/gt.jpg'));
```

otherwise you save the url string instant of the image binary into your file.

dont use `@` to prevent error messages of php functions!
just check if a valid handler is present

```
$s3Stream = fopen($s3Path . 'gt.jpg', 'w');
if( $s3Stream ) {
    fwrite($s3Stream, file_get_contents('http://sippy.in/gt.jpg'));
    fclose($s3Stream);
}
```